# NGXS: Need to call method on change of state

Tags: angular, ngxs

I want to call method by passing the new state value to that method.

I am using selector @Select(AccountState.getAccount) account$: Observable;. Is there a way we can subscribe account$ and on change of the state we can call method?

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do this. Do you mean a method from the state or a method from the subscribing component?

Comment: for example, the below component i want the read method to be called whenever tutorials state changes @Select(AccountState.getAccount) accounts$: Observable<Account>; ngOnInit() { this.accounts$.subscribe((accounts) => { this.read(accounts); }); } read(accounts) { if (accounts.length > 0) { console.log(accounts); } } . But this is not working

Comment: Hi Rich, after changing subscribe to this.store.select(AccountsState.getAccount).subscribe((accounts) => { this.read(accounts); }); } read(accounts) { if (accounts.length > 0) { console.log(accounts); } } and removing @Select(AccountState.getAccount) accounts$: Observable<Account>; it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is fairly trivial.

You should subscribe to the state in your component's `ngOnInit` method and then you can pass that state to whichever method you want.

```
@Component({
 ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Select(AccountState.getAccount) account$: Observable;
  private accountSubscription: Subscription;



  constructor(...) { ... }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.accountSubscription = this.account$.subscribe(accountState => {
      this.componentMethod(accountState);
    });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // dont forget to unsubscribe upon component's life cycle end
    // to avoid memory leaks
    this.accountSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }


  componentMethod(accountState) {
    // do something with account state

  }}

}
```